# La liaison est-elle obligatoire entre « en » et un gérondif ?

Tags: liaisons, gérondif

Puisque « en » apparaît fréquemment avant les gérondifs, j'imagine qu'on fait la liaison par habitude où un gérondif commence avec une voyelle :

> En aimant les autres...

Est-ce obligatoire, commun, rare ou interdit de faire la liaison ici ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Une double justification à la liaison obligatoire entre **en** et le gérondif qui suit :

- La liaison est obligatoire à l’**intérieur du groupe verbal** (GV) avec sujet pronominal ou **au gérondif**.
- La liaison est obligatoire après **en** préposition ou pronom conjoint.

Ma recherche d'une citation précise m'a conduit sur [cette page](http://research.jyu.fi/pisantorni/phon/90.html)  que je trouve très bien faite.

---

There are two reasons that can justify the liaison between **en** and the gerund that follows:

- The liaison is compulsory inside a verb group containing a pronominal subject or a gerund.
- The liaison is compulsory after **en** whether preposition or [clitic pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic#Other_languages) .

Looking for a reference I came up upon [this page](http://research.jyu.fi/pisantorni/phon/90.html) that I think is very good.

Comment: Haha I was going to try to answer this but you have reminded me I am very clearly not qualified, since I was basically just going to say "oui." In fact I don't even understand your answer....I thought the liaison had to do with whether the first word ended in a consonant and the second began with a vowel....this whole grammatical analysis greatly confuses me.

Comment: @Aerovistae it's a bit more complicated than that, some liaisons are forbidden, some are compulsory and others are optional. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_%28French%29